# Show $x\to \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x_k}{k}$ is a bounded on $l^1,$ and find its norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Sorry I have a question:

I am trying to prove that $f:l^1 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x_k}{k}$ is bounded, and am trying to find its norm.

$\textbf{What I do:}$

As the similar questions which we had before, we have \begin{align} |f(x)| = |\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x_k}{k}|  \leq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \mid \frac{x_k}{k} \mid &= \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \underbrace{\frac{1}{k}}_{\le 1} \mid x_k \mid \\& \le \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \mid x_k \mid \\& = ||x_k||_1 \end{align}
So we have $||f|| \le 1. $  But I think it is not correct, since for $e_n \in \ell^1$, the $n$-th canonical vector. We have:

$$\|f\| \ge \frac{|f(e_n)|}{\|e_n\|_1} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1} = \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$ 
And also some people say that its norm is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$!

Because they say, for $x\in \ell_1$ let $y(i) = \frac{\sum_{j=i}^{+\infty} x(j)}{i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x_i}{i}$. Then let $F(x) = (y(1), y(2), \ldots)$. Then we have \begin{align}||F(x)||_1 \le \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sum_{j=i}^{+\infty} \mid x(j) \mid}{i^2} &\le \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} \mid x(j) \mid}{i^2} \\&= \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{ \| x \|_1}{i^2} \\&= \frac{\pi^2}{6}\| x \|_1 \end{align}
So $\| F \| \le \frac{\pi^2}{6}\ $.

Also $\| F(e_n) \|_1 = \| (1, \frac{1}{2^2}, \ldots, , \frac{1}{n^2}, 0 ,0 \ldots) \|_1  $ goes to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ as $n \to +\infty$. So $\| F \| =\frac{\pi^2}{6} $.

Can you please let me know which of them is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Technically, all of what you did is correct. You are confusing yourself because $||f||\geq\dfrac{1}{n}\to 0$ is perfectly fine but completely unnecessary for calculating the norm.

Comment: @dezdichado Thanks! Now I just thought that if we take $x_n= (0, 0 , \ldots, 0,\frac{1}{n}, 0 , 0, \ldots, 0 ) \in \ell_1$, where $\frac{1}{n}$ is in the $n$'th component and the rest is zero, then we have $\| f \| \ge \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}} =1$. Will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've shown $\|f\|\le 1.$ Good. But showing $|f(x)|$ is small for some unit vectors in $l^1$ doesn't tell you much. Note that the sequence $1/3,-2/3,0,0,0,\dots $ is a unit vector in $l^1$ and $f$ sends this sequence to $0.$ So what?

The way to see $\|f\| = 1$ is to note that if $e_1= 1,0,0,0,\dots,$ then $\|e_1\|_1 = 1$ and $f(x) = 1.$ Thus

$$\frac{|f(e_1)|}{\|e_1\|_1} = 1.$$

This tell us $\|f\|\ge 1,$ and coupled with your first result, we have $\|f\|=1.$

Comment: Many thanks! Very nice proof! I didn't think about using $e_1$! Clever idea!

Comment: Sorry, can you please let me know what the second proof says in my statement? The one which goes to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$? That is for which function? Is it for $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x_i}{i^2}$ or $f(x) =  \frac{\sum_{i=j}^{+\infty} x_j}{i^2}$?

Comment: @user51071 I have no idea what that is all about. Looks incomprehensible to me.